# Books for the Mathematical Theory of AI/ML

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, artificial-intelligence

I am interested in the mathematical foundations of Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning. Are there any books which will describe and present the mathematical foundations in detail? I am not that interested in coding and would prefer a text which is heavy in mathematics and the theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite is [Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/understanding-machine-learning/3059695661405D25673058E43C8BE2A6). It’s presentation is very probability oriented and introduces concepts in a very concise, yet insightful way. It covers the foundations of a lot of Statistical Learning Theory and thanks to the rigorous introduction, I found it is easy to build on certain directions that interest me.

Answer (score 1):

I usually recommend **An Introduction to Statistical Learning** if you're starting out and **Elements of Statistical Learning** if you're a bit more advanced. They are both equally pleasing and completely **free**.